# Is the space $U_{0}$ constructed by J.Lindenstrauss Lipschitz complemented in $l^{1}$?

Tags: banach-spaces

In $l^{1}$, we let $x_{n}=e_{n}-\frac{e_{2n+1}+e_{2n+2}}{2}(n=1,2,...)$, where $(e_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is the unit vector basis in $l^{1}$. We let $U_{0}$ be the subspace generated by the monotone basic sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $l^{1}$. My question is whether the space $U_{0}$ is Lipschitz complemented in $l^{1}$?

Comment: Do you know of a space with the Radon Nikodym property that contains a Lipschitz complemented subspace that is not complemented? I cannot think of any.  Getting a linear projection from a Lipschitz one seems to require integration rather than differentiation, so there should be examples...

Comment: What is the paper of Lindenstrauss that this is from?

Comment: Is this the subspace of $\ell_1$ he constructed that is not isomorphic to a dual space (and therefore not complemented in $\ell_1$)?

Comment: Yes, that is the one, Phillip.  It is the first script $L_1$ subspace of $\ell_1$ that is not isomorphic to $\ell_1$.

Comment: This is from the paper of Lindenstrauss: On a certain subspace of $l_{1}$.-Dongyang Chen

Comment: Bill: Lindenstrauss really get a linear projection from a Lipschitz one by integration in 1964. He showed that in many situations the existence of a uniformly continuous projection from $Y$ onto $X$(where $X$ is a closed subspace of a Banach space $Y$)implies the existence of a bounded linear projection. This holds if $X$ is linearly complemented in $X^{**}$. If $Y$ has the Radon Nikodym property, does the existence of a Lipschitz projection from $Y$ onto $X$ implies the existence of a linear one?  I can not find such result in the Lindenstrauss's paper. Do you have any reference or proof?

Comment: @BillJohnson:Lindenstrauss really get a linear projection from a Lipschitz one by integration in 1964. He showed that in many situations the existence of a uniformly continuous projection from Y  onto X (where X  is a closed subspace of a Banach space Y )implies the existence of a bounded linear projection. This holds if X  is linearly complemented in X ∗∗  . If Y  has the Radon Nikodym property, does the existence of a Lipschitz projection from Y  onto X  implies the existence of a linear one? I can not find such result in the Lindenstrauss's paper. Do you have any reference or proof?